# IIS 8.5 Basic authentication not working - internal error 500.19

Tags: iis, web-server, http-basic-authentication

I have Basic Auth enabled for the specific folder and anonymous disabled. I also have created users, however I get a "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." message on the browser. Here is the log from the failed request tracing. I have been looking at this for hours but not been able to solve it.

UPDATE: The same error triggers when I access any non existing page, for example `http://144.144.144.144/asdasoidjasoida`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="http://144.144.144.144:80/admin/"
               siteId="1"
               appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
               processId="820"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500.19"
               triggerStatusCode="500.19"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-29T15:24:04.662Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="820" ThreadID="3756"/>
  <Computer>OWNEROR-9DTV6I9</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="SiteId">1</Data>
  <Data Name="AppPoolId">DefaultAppPool</Data>
  <Data Name="ConnId">1610612749</Data>
  <Data Name="RawConnId">0</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestURL">http://144.144.144.144:80/admin/</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestVerb">GET</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="el-GR">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>33</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-29T15:24:04.662Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="820" ThreadID="3756"/>
  <Computer>OWNEROR-9DTV6I9</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">19</Data>
  <Data Name="FileNameOrURL"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="el-GR">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-09-29T15:24:04.662Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="820" ThreadID="3756"/>
  <Computer>OWNEROR-9DTV6I9</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{8000000E-0002-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesSent">222</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesReceived">466</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">19</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="el-GR">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_END</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
</failedRequest>
```

The server specs are: 64bit Windows 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. Does someone know what is going on ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IIS stores a web.config file in each site's root directory (for example, C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web.config).  The file is probably corrupt, maybe a missing tag?

I've encountered the problem before, especially when trying URL rewrite through the GUI.  I found the easiest way around it is to create a new site, and copy the old site contents - **except for the ApplicationHost.config file and/or Web.config file** - to the new site.  (If you're using app pools, dont forget to give the app pool access to the new site through the security tab).  Then keep backups of web.config (and ApplicationHost.config, if you have one).

More information about 500.19 in IIS here:

[IIS 500.19 error explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055)

If re-creating the site doesn't solve the issue then you may want to check that your application pool has read and execute permissions to the site directory (write permissions too if you need them).  I usually do this:

1. In File Explorer, go to the top-level site directory, right-click, and select properties (for example, properties of C:\Inetpub\wwwroot)
2. Go to the Security tab and click Edit, then Add.
3. If your machine is in a domain, click on Locations and select the machine, not the domain tree, then click OK.
4. In the textbox next to the "Check Names" button type this: "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" and press Check Names.  If you typed it right the "IIS AppPool" will go away and DefaultAppPool will be underlined.
5. Give at least read&execute permissions and OK/Apply out of the boxes.

Try visiting the site again (doing an *iisreset* before hand doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 0):

it seems the following lines in web.config caused the trouble. still don't know why.

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\notfound.htm" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
```